# jquery not working on firefox but working on console

Tags: jquery, html

Please assist me with below.
The buttons I have on the div are not working on firefox, but when I write the code on console it works perfectly.

Below is one of those buttons (all defined within the doc.ready):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#close").click(function() {
        disablediv();
    });
});
```

code for disablediv :

```
var divstatus = 0;

function disablediv() {

    if(divStatus == 1) { 

        $("#add_new_input").val('');
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#error").html("");

        divStatus = 0;  
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
I tried a lot of options like window.load, including in  and so on, but its not working. Since it works on console it means no syntax errors am I right?

Comment: show code for disablediv();

Comment: ok sure and note that it works on console

Comment: It might also be useful to dump out `$("button:close")` to make sure it's selecting something when the document is ready.

Comment: Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`, if you are using a lot of libraries.

Comment: Do you get any errors on your error console?

Comment: no errors i replaced it with jQuery did not work out

Comment: Is `<button id="close">` added after the document is loaded?

Comment: I might be wrong but try to use function expression instead of declaration. Sometimes it can cause a lot of troubles if you do not understand what hoisting is. Instead of `function disablediv() { }` use `var disablediv = function() { }`

Comment: Can you include the markup or a link to a jsFiddle with everything required to reproduce the error? Even without syntax errors, there could be other kinds of problems with your code.. (also, where is `divStatus` declared?)

Comment: @AhmadAlfy That's not going to help at all.

Comment: @jack it would not work on chrome if it was not defined right ? the div is defined from the start with the buttons but set to hidden when you click a link it shows

Comment: So, reproduce it by creating a fiddle; it's kind of difficult to say what's wrong.

Comment: could it be the version of jquery i am using ?? it is jquery-1.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why is it working in the first place:

```
var divstatus = 0;

function disablediv() {

if(divStatus == 1) { 
...
}
```

`divstatus` is not the same as `divStatus`. Also if it is zero by default, the `if` condition will never be `true`.

After fixing these 2 things it is working in FF (with newer jQuery, I can't use that old in a fiddle and you shouldn't use it either):
[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/YWsxq/)

Comment: ohhh yes u are right it is because i added the declaration manually when i saw a comment asking about the initial value of it ... the code is a little big ,,, but sure u as a programmer should conclude that i set divstatus =1 on divload function ... then hide it and set it to 0 :)

Comment: it can take a day to fix a variable name typo :) anyway it is still working as you can see on the link, so the issue is not with this code part... maybe it is the JS code position: in my sample everything is in `$(document).ready(function(){ })`, however the disableddiv and the variable can be in a `<script>` block or in a JS file too...

Answer (score 0):

Is that button generated on the fly, dynamically ?

well, it seems so. If that is the case, then, try using

```
$("button#close").live('click',(function() {
    disablediv();
});
```

I faced similar issues before and solved it with this method.

Hope it helps !

Comment: `live` was deprecated in 2011, and since January this year is removed.  Basically they renamed it to `on`.

Comment: Simply renaming it to `on` won't have delegation effect. http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events